# Node.js: can not store req.session as reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I have a variable `a` that refers to the `req.session` object, however, when I later changed that `req.session` object, it is not changed in `a`, why?

```
var a;

app.post('/set', function(req, res){
    a = req.session; // now a is a reference to req.session
    res.end();
});

app.post('/change', function(req, res){
    req.session.changed = true;
    console.log(a); // a has no attribute 'changed', why?
    res.end();
});
```

To execute I first did POST /set, then I did POST /change

Comment: Why do you need that?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work in the way you expect because the session object will be recreated *per request*. This line of code

```
req.session.changed = true;
```

adds an [object-specific property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model#Adding_properties) which means it will only be set on that particular `req.session` object, all other instances to `req.session` will not change. If you want *all* instances of `req.session` to have the `changed` property then you would need to add a *prototype* property to the underlying type e.g.

```
SessionType.prototype.changed = true;
```

However, you should rethink your approach here because If 2 subsequent `POST /set` requests are made then you can't guarentee that the correct session is going to be used in the `POST /change`.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `a = req.session;` you're setting the variable `a` to what the current `req.session` object contains. So when you access `POST /change` variable `a` is still the same value from what `req.session` contained when you set it in `POST /set`.

To go around this, you'd have to set `a = req.session;` again in `POST /change`, like this:

```
app.post('/change', function(req, res){
    req.session.changed = true;
    a = req.session;
    console.log(a); // a has no attribute 'changed', why?
    res.end();
});
```

I don't understand why you'd want to do this, as using the `a` variable in production would break your session handling as it would be overwritten by someone else's session in many cases.